# How to remove the right margin of the last section of every row

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to create a grid of up to four columns for a WordPress theme. I use:

```
display:inline-block;
```

I also vertically aligned my sections to the top:

```
vertical-align:top;
```

I used margins to the right to separate each column. I need to remove the right margin of the last section of every row. To do that, I tried using:

```
.twobg:nth-of-type(2n+2), .twodarkbg:nth-of-type(2n+2), .two:nth-of-type(2n+2), .twobgborder:nth-of-type(2n+2), .twobgdashedborder:nth-of-type(odd) {
margin-right: 0;
}

.threebg:nth-of-type(3n+3), .threedarkbg:nth-of-type(3n+3), .three:nth-of-type(3n+3), .threebgborder:nth-of-type(3n+3), .threebgdashedborder:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
margin-right:0;
}

.fourbg:nth-of-type(4n+4), .fourdarkbg:nth-of-type(4n+4), .four:nth-of-type(4n+4), .fourbgborder:nth--of-type(4n+4), .fourbgdashedborder:nth--of-type(4n+4) {
margin-right:0;
}
```

However, when I use this, it gets mixed up with my other grids. I tried nth-child but it does the same thing. I need help! Why isin't this working? And what should I do?

Here, you can see the grid live. http://michellecantin.ca/test/features/grids/

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: just use (2n) not (2n + 2)

Comment: I tried, it does the same thing.

Comment: The problem is being caused by using `display: inline-block;`. An `inline-block` has a default `margin-right: 4px;` and therefor by using `margin-right: 0;` will not fix the problem because there is still a default `4px;`.

Comment: This should help you out, http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/.

Comment: I already defined `margin-right:` as `1%`